# Cassandra change comparator default order

Tags: nosql, cassandra

I create the following dynamic column:

```
CREATE COLUMN FAMILY messages with comparator=DateType and key_validation_class=UTF8Type and default_validation_class=UTF8Type;
```

Everything is perfect,but when I list all messages

```
list messages;
```

or fetching it using Hector, I'm getting it in ascending order (latest date shown last).

Is there any way to change comparator or timestamp order when creating that Column Family?

How should I take care of situation when I need to list result in descending order (showing the latest day first)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create column family with comparator: `ReversedType(DateType)`

In `RangeSliceQuery`, while building range you should specify reverse parameter as true which will pull the results in descending order.